# Deploying ASP.NET application on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I am new in Web applications. I want to deploy my web applications on IIS. However, I am getting the following error:

```
HTTP Error 500.22 - Internal Server Error
An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode. Detailed Error Information
Module ConfigurationValidationModule 
Notification BeginRequest 
Handler StaticFile 
Error Code 0x80070032 
Requested URL http://localhost:80/ 
Physical Path C:\Users\Taiseer\Desktop\UBC Course(term 2)\Software Engineering\Project-Doloto\wwwroot 
Logon Method Not yet determined 
Logon User Not yet determined
```

Any suggestions would be helpful. Could you please let me know any link or reference where the process is described step by step.

Thanks.

Comment: Your tag says "IIS6", but isn't it "IIS7"?

Answer (score 2):

To run your application in IIS using integrated mode, move the `system.web\httpHandlers` and `system.web\httpModules` sections into system.webServer and rename them to "handlers" and "modules," respectively. This should get you closer to a valid integrated mode configuration for IIS.

Comment: "Closer" doesn't solve the problem. Refer to the answer you voted down for a workaround that DOES solve it.

Comment: (Didn't mean to down-vote your answer - undid it.) But without seeing the actual config file I can't tell how to make the configuration valid, I'm just suggesting two points that I know are probably in the config file and would need to be moved.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that your application is not coded to run in Integrated Pipeline Mode.

You would eliminate this error by switching to Classic mode for your AppPool. Alternatively, you can update your code to run in Integrated Pipeline Mode.

Comment: No reason to continue using classic mode. See my answer for more info.

Comment: @Josh M: No answer here... and the alternative is there.